# Can someone explain what this does? (malicious)

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

If you enter this into your terminal CPU/memory usage will spike out of control instantly and trigger an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you I tried searching for something I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

The `:(){ ... }` part defines a function named `:` that, when called, executes `:|:&`, which is calling itself (`:`) and then piping (`|`) that into the input of itself forked (`:&`, `&` means "fork"). The final `;:` just terminates the function definition and calls it.

Basically, it runs a function that calls itself twice.